# outputting property in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am using the following javascript:

```
    var hours = $(".input_hr");
    var minutes = $(".input_min");
    var categories = $(".input_cat");
    for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
        if (categories[i].value === "Entertainment") {
            category_hours.Entertainment.push({hour:hours[i].value,minute:minutes[i].value});//add object literal
        };

    }
```

To structure my data like this:

```
category_hours = {

  Entertainment = [{hour:   ,minute:  }]
}
```

I want to console log the "hour" property.  I have tried using:

```
jQuery.each(category_hours, function() {
              console.log(Entertainment.hour)
        })
```

But I keep getting an error message that says "Entertainment is not defined".

If I do `console.log(this.Entertainment.hour)` I get "property of hour is not defined"

Comment: Maybe `console.log(this.Entertainment.hour)`  or `jQuery.each(category_hours.Entertainment, `

Comment: When i try console.log(this.Entertainment.hour) it says that hour is not defined.

Comment: In the second case you should try `this.hour`.

Comment: Can I post an answer of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over the `Entertainment` array because your `category_hours` isn't an array, it is defined as an object:

```
category_hours = {
```

So this may work:

```
jQuery.each(category_hours.Entertainment, function () {
    console.log(this.hour);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hours = $(".input_hr");
var minutes = $(".input_min");
var categories = $(".input_cat");
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    if (categories[i].value === "Entertainment") {
        category_hours.Entertainment.push({hour: hours[i].value, minute: minutes[i].value});
    }
}
jQuery.each(category_hours.Entertainment, function (index,elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});
```